# Get size of .so files in APK using aapt

Tags: apk, size, aapt, .so

I've tried using `aapt` commands to get `.so` files in APK,

```
   aapt l my_apk.apk | grep .so
```

but can we get the actual sizes of them?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAPT only handles assets and resources.

Try instead to look at the files using zip commands, e.g.

```
zipinfo my_app.apk | grep .so
```